# CSS positioning with animation

Tags: jquery, positioning, css

[image]

I need to center the mainBox div and make it from the beginning in the center of the page. As for the gameArea it must be from the beginning on its place like it is on the image shown. Information panel must slide in from the left and take place without moving other elements after animation. Is it real without positioning it in px?

```
#mainBox {
   overflow: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 500px;
   width: 1000px;
   position: relative;
   ...
}
#informationPanel {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    ...
}
#gameArea {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eatmypants/VXgpp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left:200px;` to `#gameArea` .

If that's what I understood that you want.

Comment: Or considering you dont want to push the item with the `left` property, you could alternatively use `float: right;` and `margin-right:30px;`, removing `position:absolute;`.